# multiprocessing and torch.tensor, Cannot allocate memory error

Tags: python, torch

Consider the simple example in the following, if I return a list at `func`, there will be no error,
if I return a `torch.tensor` I will get this error:

```sh
/work/aten/src/ATen/MapAllocator.cpp":263, please report a bug to PyTorch. unable to open shared memory object </torch_326297_506> in read-write mode')'
```

and If it use  `set_sharing_strategy`, to avoid this error:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import sleep
import torch


class A:
    def __init__(self, n_job, N):
        self.n_job = n_job
        self.N = N

    
    def func(self, i):
        # sleep(1)
        print(i)
        return torch.as_tensor([i])
        # return [i]

    data = []

    def read(self):

        torch.multiprocessing.set_sharing_strategy('file_system')

        with Pool(processes=self.n_job) as pool:
            data = pool.map(self.func, range(self.N))
    
        return data
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A(10, 2**16)
    data = a.read()


    print(len(data))
```

I get another error says

```sh
MapAllocator.cpp":323, please report a bug to PyTorch. unable to mmap 72 bytes from file </torch_326588_5707>: Cannot allocate memory (12)
```

is there any solution?
I need to return the tensor, so just removing the tensor is not an option.

Comment: I suggest you start by following the instructions in the message. That may lead you at least to an understanding of the problem, and, who knows? maybe even a solution.

Comment: [Link to bug report](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/75662)